# Auto date/time stamp doesn't work sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if its because I'm using Office 2016 or if my file is getting too large (450KB) but occasionally my date/time stamp code does not work (run time error). Code and form was developed when I was using excel 2013 I believe.

Code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim CC As Range
Dim CB As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
   For Each CC In Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target)
        If CC.Value <> "" Then
           CC.Offset(, -2).Value = Date & " "
           CC.Offset(, -2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        End If
   Next CC
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.EnableEvents = False
If Not Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    For Each CC In Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target)
        If CC.Value <> "" Then
           CC.Offset(, -1).Value = Time & " "
           CC.Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
        End If
    Next CC
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the code and checked to see whether it is executed and the if conditions are met?

Comment: You also don't need two blocks of code that are essentially the same, you can write in both cells in one block of code. You should, in line with this, only turn EnableEvents off and on once - this might account for an issue with the code.

Comment: Suggest you put the trailing space behind the date into the number format and remove it from the .Value. e.g. `CC.Offset(, -2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy_)"`

Comment: Thanks all, I will try the code provided and report back in a few days to see if the issue has been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the two cell writes together; the original two referenced the same range.
2. Put the trailing space into the cell number/date format. A trailing space in the actual value could change the value to text.
3. No need to set or declare anything until you know you actually require it. Don't declare vars you don't intend to use.
4. A little error control is never a bad thing.

Code rewrite:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       on error goto safe_exit
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Dim CC As Range
       For Each CC In Intersect(Range("C16:C101"), Target)
           If CC.Value <> "" Then
               CC.Offset(, -1).Value = Time
               CC.Offset(, -2).Value = Date
               CC.Offset(, -1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm_)"
               CC.Offset(, -2).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy_)"
           End If
       Next CC
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```